# How to change legend name and legend values?

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my code

```
p <- ggplot(data=predicted.data, aes(x=rank, y=probability.of.edu)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=edu), shape=4, stroke=2, size=5) +
  xlab("Index") +
  ylab("Predicted probability of education dependence") 
p
```

Variable `edu` is binary with values 0, 1.

Output looks like:

[image]

I want to change legend title, and legend values.
It will be like:

[image]

Comment: It would be easiest to change your `edu` variable to a factor since it's currently formatted as a numeric. Then use `+ labs(color = "New title"` to adjust the legend title. Add a reprex and I can help you with a fuller answer.

Comment: Oh bugger, thanks a lot. Sometimes a seemingly unsolvable problem has a very simple solution. Don't need any more help, thank you buddy.